# Не работает turtle на Mac

Tags: python, многопоточность, turtle

Есть такой вот код. По задумке он должен рисовать картинку под музыку, но выдает просто черное окно, хотя музыка воспроизводится. Что я делаю не так?

[image: На картинке виден результат работы программы. Просто черный экран]

```
import turtle
import math
from playsound import *
from threading import *


def xt(t):
    return 16 * math.sin(t) ** 3


def yt(t):
    return 13 * math.cos(t) - 5 \
           * math.cos(2 * t) - 2 * \
           math.cos(3 * t) - math.cos(4 * t)


def one():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.speed(500)
    turtle.colormode(255)
    turtle.Screen().bgcolor(0, 0, 0)
    for i in range(2550):
        t.goto((xt(i) * 20, yt(i) * 20))
        t.pencolor((255 - i) % 255, i % 255, (255 + i) // 2 % 255)
        t.goto(0, 0)
    t.hideturtle()
    turtle.update()
    turtle.mainloop()


def mus():
    playsound('music.mp3')


T2 = Thread(target = mus)

T2.start()

one()
```

Comment: Что то не видно import turtle.

Comment: Забыл скопировать

Answer (score 0):

Юзаю Python3.11 в IDLE:

1. Подключить playsound следующим образом:

from playsound import playsound

2.Далее в терминале:

pip3 install PyObjC

3.И графика рисуется и музыка воспроизводится) Наслаждаюсь!)